# How to make scheduled post in Blogger with PHP

Tags: post, google-api, blogger

In http://code.google.com/apis/blogger/docs/1.0/developers_guide_php.html#CreatingDraftEntries google give nice sample Creating a draft blog post.

But how to set date or time to draft post? so draft post will automatic publish at specific time.

Answer (score 1):

Use the <published> tag to set the date. [Here is the full description](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/2.0/reference#PublicationUpdatedDates)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to publish a scheduled post in Blogger.One is to use the 'Post options' and select 'scheduled at' the insert the time. another is to use Windows Live Writer and schedule posts. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but i need write function in PHP

Comment: but i need post blogger via php-blogger-api, not software like windows writer